# How to disable springfox import on openApi generation?

Tags: gradle, openapi-generator, springfox-boot-starter

I would like to replace openapi generator plugin from 5.0.0 to 5.1.0. If I build my project it automatically imports `import springfox.documentation.annotations.ApiIgnore;` to my all generated by API interfaces.

How can I ignore this implementation?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

add dependency to project: implementation "io.springfox:springfox-core"

Comment: This doesn't answer the poster's question.  He didn't ask how to make the error go away, but how to not add the import.

Answer (score 2):

Update openapi generator plugin to **5.3.0** or more

Answer (score 0):

Need to add next settings

```
additionalProperties: [
   apiFirst: true
]
```

Here a [code](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/c974c512ff590c797db9f3e93c079017d65d3dcd/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/java/org/openapitools/codegen/languages/SpringCodegen.java#L456) where **useSpringfox** property populated.

[Link](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/8192) to the similar conversation.